# Missing print statement

Tags: python, printing

I've written a program that asks a user for a post code. Here's the code:

```
_code = str(input('Enter your post code: '))

_exit = True
while _exit:
    print(_code)
    while len(_code) != 5:
        if  len(_code) > 5:
            print("to long")
            _code = str(input('Enter your post code: '))
        elif len(_code) < 5:
            print("to short")
            _code = str(input('Enter your post code: '))
        else: 
            print('post code is: ' + str(_code))
    break
```

The problem is when I start the program it works fine, but when the input has got a `len(_code)` equal to `5` it should jump to else statement but it doesn't. It just stops running program (break). I expect the program to print:

post code is: xxxxx

I've downloaded QPython 1.2.7 on my mobile phone, and there it works perfectly!

Comment: The code is un-readable due to no indent. Please format it properly using code blocks (four spaces)

Comment: you may have an indentation problem that you don't have on your mobile phone. This code should work, even if not optimal.

Comment: works for me on my PC.

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers, please accept it. You could also add your own answer if the existing one is incomplete / incorrect

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to hit the `else` clause.  If `len(_code)` is 5 you are NOT getting into this

```
while len(_code) != 5:
```

So you are not getting into the `if/else` in there

I think you just want to get rid of that while statement.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at you code it seems like you should simply get rid of the `else` block and move it outside the `while` block. This is because the `while` loop aims to keep asking the user for an input *as long as* he doesn't input `5`.

On receiving `5`, he should *not* be inside the `while` block. Try to write this instead,

```
while len(_code) != 5:
    if  len(_code) > 5:
        print("too long")
        _code = str(input('Enter your post code: '))
    elif len(_code) < 5:
        print("too short")
        _code = str(input('Enter your post code: '))
# The print is no longer inside an `else` block
# It's moved outside the loop
print('post code is: ' + str(_code))
```

---

As further improvements, you could move `_code = str(input('Enter your post code: '))` outside the `if` / `elsif` all together. Something like this would work,

```
# Initialize to zero length
_code = ""
while len(_code) != 5:
    # Executed each time at beginning of `while`
    _code = str(input('Enter your post code: '))
    if  len(_code) > 5:
        print("too long")
    elif len(_code) < 5:
        print("too short")
print('post code is: ' + str(_code))
```

Comment: Thaks to you all for answers, especially for martianwars! 
Now it works great, I'm still wondering why my previous code worked fine on my mobile, but not on my pc? I'll figure this out tomorrow, now it's time for sleep with my while statement ;)

Comment: Don't forget to accept a correct answer. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The else clause is inside the while loop so won't be executed when len(_code)=5. 
If you restructure your code like below, it should work.

```
_code = str(input('Enter your post code: '))

_exit = True
while _exit:
    print(_code)
    while len(_code) != 5:
        if  len(_code) > 5:
            print("too long")
            _code = str(input('Enter your post code: '))
        elif len(_code) < 5:
            print("too short")
            _code = str(input('Enter your post code: ')) 
    print('post code is: ' + str(_code))
    break
```